# Retrieve Image Field From Database using NHibernate UniqueResult()

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, sybase

I'm trying to retrieve an Image datatype field from a Sybase database using NHibernate BUT the data is being truncated after 32768 bytes is retrieved.

Sample code :

```
        using (var session = NHibernateBroker.OpenSession())
        {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("SELECT file ");
                sb.Append("FROM newTable WHERE name = 't'");

                var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sb.ToString());
                var data = query.UniqueResult(); //This returns a byte array. 
                //Files smaller than 32768 bytes are retrieved without any issue
        }
```

How can I retrieve files larger than 32768 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that Sybase limits the text/image data type transfers to [32KB by default](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc34201_1500/html/dco_150/dco_150126.htm).

Added the following to my connection string to override it -

```
textsize=500000
```

[Additional info](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive/)